# how to customize dialog size in spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-spinner

this is my spinner's code

XML code

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/amountContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amountTitleTV" />
```

Kotlin code

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter((this.activity as Context), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, entries.toList())
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.amount_picker)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice)
```

How to make a width to the dialog? like 60% of the page's width or even 300dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no way to customize the dialog spinner but using dropdown mode you can customize and it will look like dialog spinner.

Add  this attribute to spinner in xml file this will give full width to your spinner

```
 // this width is for dialog
 android:dropDownWidth="300dp"

//drop down with only work when spinner mode is drop down
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
```

By using  `dropDownVerticalOffset` attribute you give space between spinner and it dropdown .This will help to look like Dialog spinner`

```
 android:dropDownVerticalOffset="@dimen/_2sdp"
```

Comment: I used this only android:dropDownWidth="300dp" since i want it dialog not dropdown, but it didn't work, it work only with the dropdown not the dialog

Comment: android:dropDownWidth only work when android:spinnerMode="dropdown" . I am updating my answer